# Jogo de Batalha Naval em C

Tags: c

Estou fazendo um jogo de batalha naval em C e gostaria de saber como posso fazer para os tiros dados pelo usuário aparecerem em uma matriz do mapa. Aqui está parte do código:

```
int batalha (char luta)
{
    char mapa[9][9];
    char tiro_letra;
    int tiro_numero;
    int torpedos = 20;
    int x,y;
    int acertos = 0;
    for (x = 0; x < 9; x++)
    {
        for (y = 0; y < 9; y++)
        {
            mapa [x][y] = '.';
        }
    }
    mapa [0][0] = ' ';
    mapa [0][1] = 'A';
    mapa [0][2] = 'B';
    mapa [0][3] = 'C';
    mapa [0][4] = 'D';
    mapa [0][5] = 'E';
    mapa [0][6] = 'F';
    mapa [0][7] = 'G';
    mapa [0][8] = 'H';

    mapa [1][0] = 49;
    mapa [2][0] = 50;
    mapa [3][0] = 51;
    mapa [4][0] = 52;
    mapa [5][0] = 53;
    mapa [6][0] = 54;
    mapa [7][0] = 55;
    mapa [8][0] = 56;

    for (x = 0; x < 9; x++)
    {
        for (y = 0; y < 9; y++)
        {
            printf ("%c\t", mapa [x][y]);
        }
        putchar ('\n');
    }
    x = 0;
    while (x < 20)
    {
        scanf ("%c %d", &tiro_letra, &tiro_numero);
        if ((tiro_letra == 'A' && tiro_numero == 7) || (tiro_letra == 'B' && tiro_numero == 2)||
        (tiro_letra == 'B' && tiro_numero == 7) || (tiro_letra == 'C' && tiro_numero == 2)||
        (tiro_letra == 'C' && tiro_numero == 7) || (tiro_letra == 'E' && tiro_numero == 2)||
        (tiro_letra == 'E' && tiro_numero == 5) || (tiro_letra == 'F' && tiro_numero == 2)||
        (tiro_letra == 'F' && tiro_numero == 5) || (tiro_letra == 'G' && tiro_numero == 2)||
        (tiro_letra == 'G' && tiro_numero == 5) || (tiro_letra == 'H' && tiro_numero == 2))
        {
            printf ("BOMBA!!! %d torpedos restantes! %d acertos!\n", torpedos-1, acertos+1);
            acertos = acertos+1;
            // Colocar aqui onde o tiro foi dado //
            scanf ("%c %d", &tiro_letra, &tiro_numero);
        }
        else
        {
            printf ("ÁGUA!!! %d torpedos restantes!\n", torpedos-1);
            // Colocar aqui onde o tiro foi dado //
            scanf ("%c %d", &tiro_letra, &tiro_numero);
        }
        if (acertos == 12)
        {
            printf ("Todos os navios inimigos foram afundados! Parabéns, Capitão!\n");
            return (0);
        }
        else if (torpedos == 2)
        {
            printf ("Você ficou sem torpedos! Você foi derrotado!\n");
        return (0);
        }
        x++;
        torpedos--;
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Não repita perguntas, siga as orientações dadas na pergunta original https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/588576/3635 e edite-a para melhora-la e se adequar ao [objetivo do site](/help). Os comentários aqui foram bloqueados, podem continuar a comentar na pergunta original.